# CiviEvent : Error on event registration Thank-you page

Tags: wordpress, civievent, error, online-registration

We have a trouble with CiviEvent with **CiviCRM 5.54.1, Wordpress 6.1**

We can do the register, send mail but when the ThankYou page is display a message error is display : **"Could not find valid value for id
Return to home page."**

**URL of thank you page**: http://domain.org/fr/civicrm/?civiwp=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fevent%2Fregister&_qf_ThankYou_display=true&qfKey=CRMEventControllerRegistration30...

**From the error log :**

```
nov. 02 19:31:37  [error] 
$Fatal Error Details = array:3 [
  "message" => "Aucune donnée valide n'a pu être trouvée pour la variable « id »."
  "code" => null
  "exception" => CRM_Core_Exception {#12638
    -errorData: array:1 [
      "error_code" => 0
    ]
    #cause: null
    -_trace: null
    #message: "Aucune donnée valide n'a pu être trouvée pour la variable « id »."
    #code: 0
    #file: "/home/domaine/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Request.php"
    #line: 98
    trace: {
      /home/domaine/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Request.php:98 {
        › if (!isset($value) && $abort) {
        ›   throw new CRM_Core_Exception(ts('Could not find valid value for %1', [1 => $name]));
        › }
      }
      /home/domaine/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Event/StateMachine/Registration.php:27 { …}
      /home/domaine/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Event/Controller/Registration.php:27 { …}
      /home/domaine/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:314 { …}
      /home/domaine/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:69 { …}
      /home/domaine/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:36 { …}
      /home/domaine/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php:1199 { …}
      /home/domaine/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/includes/civicrm.basepage.php:380 { …}
      /home/domaine/www/www/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:308 { …}
      /home/domaine/www/www/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:332 { …}
      /home/domaine/www/www/wp-includes/plugin.php:565 { …}
      /home/domaine/www/www/wp-includes/class-wp.php:797 { …}
      /home/domaine/www/www/wp-includes/functions.php:1332 { …}
      /home/domaine/www/www/wp-blog-header.php:16 { …}
      /home/domaine/www/www/index.php:17 { …}
    }
  }
]


nov. 02 19:31:37  [debug] $backTrace = #0 /home/domaine/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(441): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 /home/domaine/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(39): CRM_Core_Error::handleUnhandledException(Object(CRM_Core_Exception))
#2 /home/domaine/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1199): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#3 /home/domaine/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/includes/civicrm.basepage.php(380): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke()
#4 /home/domaine/www/www/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(308): CiviCRM_For_WordPress_Basepage->basepage_handler(Object(WP))
#5 /home/domaine/www/www/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(332): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, (Array:1))
#6 /home/domaine/www/www/wp-includes/plugin.php(565): WP_Hook->do_action((Array:1))
#7 /home/domaine/www/www/wp-includes/class-wp.php(797): do_action_ref_array("wp", (Array:1))
#8 /home/domaine/www/www/wp-includes/functions.php(1332): WP->main("")
#9 /home/domaine/www/www/wp-blog-header.php(16): wp()
#10 /home/domaine/www/www/index.php(17): require("/home/domaine/www/www/wp-blog-header.php")
#11 {main}
```

**Already done :**
I already check that a WP page with the 'civicrm' permalink is present and a 'base page' within CiviCRM is configurated in Administer->System setting->CMS Database Integration

Do you have an idea of the root cause ?

Comment: I'd look at https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/41578/could-not-find-valid-value-for-id-after-event-registration-on-wordpress-5-9-1/ The two answers should help get you sorted

Answer (score 2):

Yes I found :-)
the civicrm.settings.php must have this bit of code:

````
   if ( function_exists('variable_get') && variable_get('clean_url', '0') != '0') {
     define('CIVICRM_CLEANURL', 1 );
   }
   elseif ( function_exists('config_get') && config_get('system.core', 'clean_url') != 0) {
     define('CIVICRM_CLEANURL', 1 );
   }
   elseif( function_exists('get_option') && get_option('permalink_structure') != '' ) {
     define('CIVICRM_CLEANURL', 1 );
   }
   else {
     define('CIVICRM_CLEANURL', 0);
   }
 }```
````