# CIVI CRM Donation Form is not working - no thank you page

Tags: contributions

I am currently using the CIVI CRM plugin in WordPress and have integrated the Donation form on our website at https://pulsevoices.org/energize-pulse. However, when users try to submit the form, it takes a considerably long time to process, and an error message appears, stating: "Your browser session has expired, and we are unable to complete your form submission. We have returned you to the initial step so you can complete and resubmit the form." Despite the error, the payment is successfully processed, and users receive the email receipt. The problem is that instead of redirecting users to the thank you page, they are prompted to resubmit the form. You can see a screenshot of the issue here: https://prnt.sc/wUrHtNSWd5VE. We are currently using Stripe as the payment gateway.

I have thoroughly investigated the issue from my end and tried various solutions, but unfortunately, the problem persists. I also checked the settings suggested on this ticket [Payment Form Errors "Your browser session has expired and we are unable to complete your form submission" after upgrade to 5.47.2](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/41574/payment-form-errors-your-browser-session-has-expired-and-we-are-unable-to-compl). Even after updating the plugin to the latest version, we continue to face the same outcome. It's worth mentioning that the form works correctly when tested in the Test mode of the payment gateway.

Next, we have setup the site on a staging server and completely removed civicrm and implemented a fresh install but the same error happens during testing — when users try to submit the form, it takes a considerably long time to process, and an error message appears, stating: "Your browser session has expired, and we are unable to complete your form submission. We have returned you to the initial step so you can complete and resubmit the form."

It seems that there is an issue with clean URLs. Initially, the page tries to process the clean URLs but seems eventually it reverts to the old URL: https:pulsevoices.org/energize-pulse?civiwp=CiviCRM&a=civicr oute%2Ftransact&id=13&reset=1

We have already made the updates as suggested in this post: https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/integration/wordpress/clean-urls/

And we have cleaned up mixed http vs https URLs.

This issue has been occurring since mid-May 2023.

Would appreciate any feedback you can provide. Please and thank you.